# Database Table Data Types To Store Key/Value Cache

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, caching

I am working on a project that requires key/value caching function but the application will exist in a very limited environment that **does not support** any of the go-to industry standard memory caching methods such as **ASP.NET Cache, memcached, AppFabric**.

The only option we have in this restrictive environment is a MS SQL database. We have to create a simple key/value table to meet our key/value caching needs. We will most likely serialize the data as JSON but I am not sure what would be the best data type for the key. It will obviously need to be a unique key and need to be readable by the programmer getting and setting the cache. It also needs to be a fast look up since we will already be loosing performance not having access to an "in memory" cache solution.

I am use to having my primary key column be an int or bigint value. In this case should the primary key (the cache key) be a char or varchar data type as all queries will be:

```
SELECT value FROM CacheTable WHERE key = 'keyname'
```

I also saw posts about using an md5 hash but other posts pointed out that hashing cannot be relied on to produce unique keys all the time. I'm basically after some advice on the data type and rather or not the 'key' column should be the primary key or if I should still create an int or bigint primary key (even though it probably will not be used).

The end result we are after is creating a caching class similar to .NET's native caching where we can create a static class that pulls from the database table such as:

```
CustomDatabaseCache.Set(string key, object value);
CustomDatabaseCache.Get(string key)
```

Comment: How many rows do you suppose this `cache database` will need to have? Also, do you need to keep that cached values separated by sessions?

Comment: All cache values would be unique so if there was a value cached for a user's session it would have a cache key along the lines of "UserId_SessionKey".

Comment: The application will support several sub sites all with user specific content so the size of the cache table could become fairly large in the area of 100K to 500K entries. We would probably write some type of automated routine to clear out expired cache based on a created timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your scenario having a clustered primary key on your keyname column would work fine. However, it's worth experimenting with fill factors, because you want a fill factor that is low enough that you don't cause excessive page splits, but one that is high enough to keep the number of page reads low.

A clustered IDENTITY index works better in terms of eliminating page splits on the clustered index - and you could use a unique index on keyname which used an INCLUDE clause to include your values. However - in your case, I don't see the benefit in doing that because you'd have exactly the same page-split problem on your unique index, and the clustered index on keyname would be no more expensive to read because you wouldn't have any extra columns. Plus you would then have index update cost on two indexes for write.

Hope that helps.